# How to access the router USB from the internet?

Tags: router, usb, http

I want to host a simple page on the router, Here is some info's

- I have static IP to be connect to a domain
- The router is Huawei DG8045
- I connected USB to the router and formatted it as FAT32
- The router have FTP option
- The USB contain index.html file in the root folder

**My problem is: I can't access the page from outside at all or even from the lan, But I can see the file via FTP protocol from LAN or WAN**

What I'm doing wrong?!

Comment: The router has an FTP server. What you would need to host a website (index.html) is a HTTP(s) server. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol FTP is just for downloading and uploading files, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol is for webpages (among other things)

Comment: @Gantendo is it possible to make HTTP protocol work on USB?

Comment: The problem is that the router does not have a HTTP server. You could install a HTTP server on a computer, but not on the router.